# Excel string to number conversion, while getting rid of the M for a whole column

Tags: excel, data-conversion

I am working with data that was entered as a string, $105M, instead of a numerica value, 105,000,000.00

How do I convert this? I have been Googling and have looked up several times. It's referencing athlete salaries, and thus, they're all in the millions. To simplify, they just put M instead of the whole, much larger, number. I understand why, but now I can't do the sum of the columns, and I can't do much with it in my Tableau visuals. Any advice or ideas? I want to convert both the Salaries and Endorsement columns. I will attache a picture. Thanks.[image]

Comment: You could use a formula column: `=MID(C2,2,find(" ",C2)-2)*1000000` for example.

Comment: @Rory: you don't make a difference between "M" and "K".

Comment: @Dominique I didn't see the K item! Perhaps `=MID(C2,2,find(" ",C2)-2)*IF(RIGHT(C2,1)="M",1000000,1000)` then

Comment: @Rory: it's in row 31, the endorsements of "poor" Cliff Lee :-)